# Visual studio docker tools publish port when debugging

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

I'm just getting started with Docker and have installed docker for windows. 

The basic setup of docker is correct and i have been able to debug a simple Asp.Net Core app which is deployed to a container from within Visual studio (using the standard 'Run' command targeting docker).

The problem i'm having is being able to hit the endpoint hosted from within the container without using localhost i.e. using the IP of the container. I need this as i'm intending to hit the endpoint from a xamarin app.

After doing some reading, it seems i need to 'publish' the port that the application is running, in this case port 5000, but i can't seem to find where to configure visual studio to do this.

Using postman or a web browser to hit the endpoint results in the same response Empty_Response error.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://<container ip>:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ItemCheckout/ItemCheckout.csproj", "ItemCheckout/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ItemCheckout/ItemCheckout.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ItemCheckout"
RUN dotnet build "ItemCheckout.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ItemCheckout.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ItemCheckout.dll"]
```

Startup.cs:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private static readonly LoggerFactory _loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new []{new DebugLoggerProvider()});

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<ItemCheckoutDbContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                o.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://<container ip>:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Output when running:

Hosting environment: Development

Content root path: /app

Now listening on: http://`<container ip>`:5000

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

**EDIT:** Updated program.cs as per @MindSwipe's suggestion, however i am still getting the same result

Comment: Did you make sure the ASP.NET Core app is running on port 500? Can you post your `Porgram.cs` as well?

Comment: @MindSwipe added - however from what i've been reading using the ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS... line in the dockerfile is what tells asp.net core the port to use, is this not the case?

Comment: I've never heard of it, I've always use `webBuilder.UseUrls("...", "..." ...);`. Also maybe try actually using the IP instead of  `http://+:5000`

Comment: Change `http://<container ip>:5000` to `http://localhost:5000`, first make sure you are able to access the core app from postman or web browser.

Answer (score 14):

Port mapping must be specified during `docker run` command. `EXPOSE` command within dockerfile normally used for documentation purposes.

Solution: in your Visual Studio project file add the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 5000:5000</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: I have my docker file using port 80, which had restrictions so I couldn't use `-p 80:80`, so instead I used `<DockerfileRunArguments>-p 5001:80</DockerfileRunArguments>`. Then this call from my (host) machine worked: `http://localhost:5001/api/post`

Answer (score 2):

OK - from what I see - you're confusing the port on the container with the port on the host.
You have 2 sides to port mapping in Docker - the host side and the client/container side.

There's a couple of ways to solve the issue that you can't connect.

With the container running (F5 debug, command line) - execute the following command:
"docker ps -a"
You will see a list of running containers; there's a column called "Ports". Find the entry for your container - probably the solutionname:dev.  Look at the ports column, you will see AA -> BB.

AA is the port you need in your browser - that is your host port - so http://localhost:AA, or http://IP-Address:AA/

BB is the listening port on the container - in your case 5000.

Does this help?

EDIT:
change this line: ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://:5000
to ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000

This is relative to the container - not the host.